# How to oxidize black nickel plating

Tags: electroplating

Looking to force a patina on a black nickel plating over brass to mimic age.  I know black nickel can oxidize brown or yellow but I don't know how to oxidize it.  I don't see anything on the web. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: You can see the dark gray color of oxidized nickel on any electric range heating element ; they are Nichrome about 80 % Ni. I have seen many oxidized Nickel alloys, Inconels, Incoloys, high nickel stainless like HP , HK, etc ( about 32 % Ni ) ; they are all the same dark gray after heating.

Comment: You might try various selenide or sulfide chemicals used in gun bluing, but would need to experiment.